# AS3 Reference memory length/size

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I was wondering how much memory is occupied by a single reference to some object in ActionScript?

If I have for instance array of some object and want to process them at specific order I would create another array or vector of `uint` with indicies of them in first array.

I can count how much memory it will take to allocate specific  number of `uint`s but don't know how much it will take to create another array as set of references. I imagine that every reference need to have specified type of the object so it will be probably more than 32bits.

I imagine that numbers objects also need to have references at some point but if I create vector is it going to be continuous data in memory and only this vector will contain info about type of its members and how it is going to affect processing efficiency?

Maybe a simple code w will better clarify what i mean.
So, basically my question is which of those approaches are more efficient in terms of memory use (and speed also):

```
var mo, tu, we, th, fr, sa, su:Object;
var days:Array = [mo, tu, we, th, fr, sa, su];
var daysOff:Array = [mo, we, fr];

for (var i:int = 0; i < daysOff.length; i++){
    trace(daysOff);
}
```

or

```
var mo, tu, we, th, fr, sa, su:Object;
var days:Array = [mo, tu, we, th, fr, sa, su];
var daysOff:Array = [0, 2, 4];

for (var i:int = 0; i < daysOff.length; i++){
    trace(days[daysOff[i]]);

}
```

I can compare serialised data length but i'm not convinced about that since lot of data like private members are lost due to serialisation process.
Is somewhere in-depth explanation of objects references in AS3?

Comment: You could use Adobe Scout to get a baseline, then make an adjustment and see how that augments the reference/array.

Answer (score 0):

You can work out how big any object's data is by using [`ByteArray.writeObject()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#writeObject()) to serialize the data and then count the length of the byte array.

Unfortunately there is no simple way to work out the full size of the full object, with all its functions and properties. Actionscript lacks the ability to directly interact with memory areas, even with such an ability all parts of an Actionscript `Object` are themselves object references (including the functions), you would need a recursive scan to keep tunnelling through all the references until you found the base data representation.